# How to retrieve data from Firebase observable object

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, typescript2.0, angular2-components

I am using FirebaseListObservable to retrieve data, and assigned it to class level variable. When I am passing class properties to other function, it shows me below string in console.

```
{$value: "0", $key: "_1", $exists: ƒ}
```

In above code, "_1" is my property name and I assigned "0" value in it. I want to fetch "0" by doing, **this.boardItems._1**

On view I am able to access value by writing, **{{boardItems?._1.$value}}**

How to retrieve it in typescript?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md

Comment: Why I have to call again to firebase to retrieve value, I already have in my class. My class already subscribed with firebase. I just want values.

Comment: this.boardItems[_1]

Comment: Tried this.boardItems["_1"], Giving same result. Here "_1" is property name, so cannot give without double quotes.

Comment: this.boardItems["_1"]["$value] worked...
But there must be some other solution.

Comment: Its coming down as a list of objects use the the object observable which will you can then fetch the value by the key.